# Why does my DateComponents object in iOS not save to or retrieve from CloudKit correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, cloudkit, nsdatecomponents

I am using CloudKit with Swift for iOS.

I am saving an object of type DateComponents in a CloudKit field of type Bytes. When I retrieve the object, it does not have the same value as the object I originally saved.

Here is the code where I save the object to CloudKit:

```
let unsafePointer: UnsafePointer<DateComponents> = UnsafePointer<DateComponents>(&time)
let unsafeBufferPointer: UnsafeBufferPointer<DateComponents> = UnsafeBufferPointer<DateComponents>(start: unsafePointer, count: 1)
let data: Data = Data(buffer: unsafeBufferPointer)
privateRecord.setObject(data as CKRecordValue?, forKey: DatabaseNameStrings.fieldTime)
```

Here is the print result in the debug window:

> time = calendar: gregorian (autoupdatingCurrent) timeZone: America/Chicago (autoupdatingCurrent) hour: 12 minute: 0 isLeapMonth: false

Here is the code where I retrieve the object from CloudKit:

```
if let dataTime = privateRecord.object(forKey: DatabaseNameStrings.fieldTime) as? Data {
    let unsafeMutableBufferPointer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<DateComponents> = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<DateComponents>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    _ = dataTime.copyBytes(to: unsafeMutableBufferPointer)
    print("unsafeMutableBufferPointer.first =", unsafeMutableBufferPointer.first as Any)
    privateTime = unsafeMutableBufferPointer.first
}
```

Here is the print result in the debug window:

> unsafeMutableBufferPointer.first = Optional(era: 0 year: 0 month: 0 day: 0 hour: 0 minute: 0 second: 0 nanosecond: 0 weekday: 0 weekdayOrdinal: 0 quarter: 0 weekOfMonth: 0 weekOfYear: 0 yearForWeekOfYear: 0 isLeapMonth: false )

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895587/how-would-i-save-an-object-of-type-datecomponents-to-a-cloudkit-field/

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Do I need to do anything?

Comment: No, it's just a reference for people who come across this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to persist a `DateComponents` instance is the wrong approach; You have no visibility of the internal structure of the object and this structure could change with Swift or iOS updates.

Your assumption is that you can bypass the initialisation of `DateComponents` simply by restoring the bytes that represented some other instance; This is an incorrect assumption.

`DateComponents` is actually toll-free bridged to an underlying instance of `NSDateComponents`.

When you call  `UnsafeBufferPointer<DateComponents>(start: unsafePointer, count: 1)` you are accessing the Swift struct that is used to access the underlying `NSDateComponents` instance.

When you subsequently try to re-create this struct, that underlying object does not exist and you get 0s.

You should either save the specific fields required to re-create the date components (e.g. timezone, hour etc) or save a `Date` object.